# Python DB2 SSL connection

Tags: python, pandas, ssl, db2, keystore

I have been running SQL queries (client side) from **DB2** databases using **ibm_db** & **ibm_db_dbi** with pandas. However our company implemented new security standards and I would need a way to secure the connection as well.
Running **Python3.7** and **DB2 10.5**

Below is my current connection string:

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas as pd

driver = 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER'
database = 'DB0001'
hostname = 'my.host.com'
port = '1234'
protocol = 'TCPIP'
uid = 'user'
pwd = 'password'
security = 'SSL'

dsn = (
    f'DRIVER={driver};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'HOSTNAME={hostname};'
    f'PORT={port};'
    f'PROTOCOL={protocol};'
    f'UID={uid};'
    f'PWD={pwd};'
    f'SECURITY={security};'
)

test_query = 'SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1'
conn_engine = ibm_db.connect(dsn, '', '')
db_conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn_engine)

df = pd.read_sql(test_query, db_conn)
```

Is there any way to incorporate SSL for this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the following properties:

[Security](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0054070.html)=SSL, SSLClientKeystoredb, SSLClientKeystoreDBPassword or SSLClientKeystash as described at the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is, unfortunately, a little complicated, and (hopefully) your DBA can help with some of this.

If you're using a Db2 10.5 Fixpack 5 (or newer) client, then you just need to add a couple of parameters in your DSN string:

```
Security=ssl; 
SslServerCertificate=/path/to/file.arm;
```

Your DBA should be able to provide you with the SslServerCertificate file (or contents).

If you installed a Db2 client separately from the python ibm_db package, then depending on which Db2 client you have installed (i.e. providing the native libraries for `ibm_db`, you *might* need to install some additional libraries (the IBM GSKit libraries, which provide the SSL functionality for the Db2 client).

Comment: Thanks for the insights Ian! I did have GSKit already installed, so providing the path to cert seemed to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

With some newer versions of the Db2 driver and to connect to Db2 on Cloud and Db2 Warehouse on Cloud, addint just `Security=SSL;` to the list of parameters works.